# Может ли нарушаться принцип подстановки Лисков при использовании интерфейса/абстрактного класса?

Tags: java, ооп, solid

На размышления меня натолкнула вот эта статья: 
http://blog.byndyu.ru/2009/10/blog-post_29.html
Приведу немного переработанный пример из нее:

```
public interface IList {

public void add(int e);

}

public class List implements IList{

@Override
public void add(int e) {
    // добавляет элемент
}

}

public class DoubleList implements IList{

@Override
public void add(int e) {
    // добавляет элемент
    // добавляет элемент
}

}
```

Метод add в классе DoubleList добавляет элемент дважды. 
В клиентском коде можно написать примерно так:

```
public void LSPTest(IList list){
int oldLen = list.getLength();

list.add(1);

int newLen = list.getLength();

if(newLen - oldLen == 1){
    // делать что то полезное
}
}
```

Очевидно, что поведение программы будет разным, в зависимости от того, получит функция `LSPTest` объект класса `List` или `DoubleList`. Но разве это нарушает LSP? Ведь `DoubleList` наследует не класс `List`, а интерфейс `IList`. Интерфейс не может задавать никаких предусловий и постусловий (в данном случае точно не задает). И интерфейсы же для того и написаны, что бы иметь разные реализации, иногда имеющие совсем мало общего. Я всегда считал, что если бы, например, `DoubleList` был наследован от `List`, то выделение интерфейса и опускание классов на один уровень - это как раз решение проблемы при нарушении LSP. По-моему это называется факторизация. И к тому же, LSP говорит о том, что прогрмма не должна меняться, если вместо объекта базового класса подставить объект производного. Но как можно подставить что то вместо объекта базового класса, если базовый класс является абстрактным? Или тем более интерфейсом? Вместо него нельзя ничего подставить, потому что его просто нельзя создать.

Comment: Начните с того, что определите у вашего `IList` метод `length()` и напишите к нему и к `add( int e )` javadoc. То, что вы там напишете, будет ожидаемым поведением, и именно этим ожиданиям должны соответствовать реализующие объекты.

Comment: @zRrr, ну у меня же игрушечный пример. Никаких настоящих списков нет. Тут дело не в списке, а в LSP. Метод getLength() просто возвращает длину списка. То есть все определяется по Javadoc?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Интерфейс не может задавать никаких предусловий и постусловий

Формально вы правы. Объявление интерфейса само по себе не задает "материального" (назовем это так) контракта -- т.е. контракта, который может быть проверен на этапе компиляции или выполнения. Т.е. нет никаких средств, гарантирующих, что все классы, реализующие интерфейс, будут реализовывать его одинаково с т.з. LSP.

Хитрость заключается в том, что при использовании интерфейсов мы всегда говорим о "нематериальном" контракте. Он выражается в названии методов и в комментариях. Это такой неформальный уговор среди разработчиков. В случае с [`IList`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/a.html#5d74f6adfeaf6c7d) из .NET это выглядит так*:

```
// Adds an item to the list.  The exact position in the list is 
// implementation-dependent, so while ArrayList may always insert
// in the last available location, a SortedList most likely would not.
// The return value is the position the new element was inserted in.
int Add(Object value);
```

Как видно из комментария, если класс-наследник будет добавлять в список сразу два элемента, он нарушит два пункта из комментария: что добавлять должен один элемент и что метод возвращает позицию добавленного элемента (а что возвращать в случае двух элементов?).

В то же время, комментарии к методу [`ICollection<T>.Add()`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/a.html#a9bf1395d3addc77) ничего не говорят о том, что этот метод предполагает делать. И, как мы видим, это согласуется с тем, что, например, `HashSet<T>` (реализующий `ICollection<T>`) после двух вызовов метода `Add()` с одинаковыми аргументами будет содержать лишь один элемент.

Это тонкий лед, т.к., повторюсь, нет средств для обеспечения выполнения обозначенного контракта -- это лежит целиком на совести программиста. Более того, интерфейс может и не продоставлять никаких комментариев и о его контракте придется как-то догадываться -- из документации, интернета, от коллег.

Но тем не менее 99.9% разработчиков, увидев название интерфейса `IList`, будут ожидать, что метод `Add()` добавит в список один элемент. Если же вдруг этот метод будет добавлять два элемента, не добавлять ничего, или даже удалять, это очень удивит эти 99.9%. В этом, собственно, и заключается нарушение LSP.

Если вы пока не очень понимаете LSP, то забудьте на время про интерфейсы и посмотрите на примеры использования наследования классов. Например, на [классическую проблему прямоугольника и квадрата](http://sergeyteplyakov.blogspot.ru/2014/09/liskov-substitution-principle.html).

---

*желающим попудрить себе мозг читать ниже.

Метод `IList.Add()`, как мы уже видели, явно в комментарии обозначает свой контракт. А что насчет [`IList<T>`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/a.html#b19f71a84062554b)? Как видно, он наследуются от `ICollection<T>`, а это значит, что на метод `Add()` не налагается ограничений. Т.о. класс `DoubleList<T> : IList<T>` формально уже **не будет** нарушать LSP. Но бьюсь об заклад, ваши коллеги не будут рады такой реализации :).

Comment: наверное поэтому [`java.util.List`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/List.java#209) явно переопределяет все методы `java.util.Collection` с соответствующими комментариями.

Comment: @andreycha, спасибо, я понял) В этом отношении наверное намного удобнее в Eifel? Я слышал, там как то можно формализовать контракт.

Comment: @АлександрЕлизаров да, я тоже об этом слышал краем уха. Такая возможность стопроцентно заставляет не нарушать LSP.

Answer (score 4):

Именно этот вопрос я довольно детально рассматривал в статье ["Наследование интерфейсов и контракты"](http://sergeyteplyakov.blogspot.com/2012/03/blog-post.html).

Продублирую выводы, сделанные в моей статье: разные виды коллекций в .NET (для Java нужно проводить отдельные исследования) обладают разными постусловиями. Постусловие интерфейса `IList` более строгое: метод `Add` **должен** добавлять элемент, причем только один. Постусловие же базовой коллекции `ICollection` - слабее: метод `Add` не гарантирует, что элемент будет вообще добавлен, поскольку есть такие типы, как "наборы" (`HashSet` и другие), в которых не должно быть дубликатов и метод `Add` в этом случае ничего не будет делать.

В этом случае, если наша коллекция реализует `IList`, то метод `Add` этой коллекции **должен** добавить элемент, причем только один. Если же наша коллекция реализует лишь `ICollection`, то метод `Add` вполне может и не добавлять элементы.

> Интерфейс не может задавать никаких предусловий и постусловий

В общем случае - это не так. В языке может не быть инструментов для формального определения предусловий/постусловий для интерфейсов или абстрактных классов, но интерфейс ими обладает.

Например, в .NET можно использовать библиотеку [Code Contracts](https://github.com/Microsoft/CodeContracts/), которая позволяет задать контракты интерфейсов. При этом есть аннотация стандартной библиотеки, в которой можно посмотреть, какие контракты у стандартных интерфейсов. Вот, например, контракт метода [`ICollection<T>.Add`](https://github.com/Microsoft/CodeContracts/blob/79a04c96679b6d400c286dd62d6a2ec77462da72/Microsoft.Research/Contracts/MsCorlib/System.Collections.Generic.ICollection.cs#L141):

```
public void Add(T item)
{
  //Contract.Requires(!@this.IsReadOnly);
  // The Ensures below is tricky for wrappers. Needs quantified invariant in wrapper to prove wrapper correct
  //   Forall(value => !m_backing.Contains(value) || this.Contains(value) ) 
  //Contract.Ensures(this.Contains(item)); 
  Contract.Ensures(this.Count >= Contract.OldValue(this.Count));
  throw new global::System.NotImplementedException();
}
```

Есть популярное мнение, что реализация интерфейса может делать все, что угодно, но в этом случае у клиента этого интерфейса пропадает возможность понять, а что же от этого зверя ожидать.

Принцип LSP вообще невозможен без контрактов. Контракт определяет ожидаемое поведение, а нарушение LSP как раз и говорит о нарушении этого самого поведения. Тут можно провести аналогию с багами: помимо явных крэшей, мы не можем говорить, является ли поведение ошибкой или нет, если мы не знаем, какое поведение является ожидаемым.

Comment: Спасибо, стало понятнее. Но не до конца. То есть, если поведение интерфейса просто закомментированно, то, нарушая эти комментарии, в классе реализующем интерфейс, мы уже нарушаем LSP?